# Supertest unit test timing out when controller sets session data

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, supertest

I am trying to run a unit test on my application but the unit test timesout. When I looked deeper into it I found out that it is timing out where the application is trying to set the session data. If I remove the session setting line of code the unit test continues ( but fails because the session data is required ).

```
// unit test code;
describe('Check if endpoint are reachable', () => {

  before(function(done) {
    // call /router to generate session;
    AGENT.get('/router')
        .query(clientData)
        .expect(302)
        .end((err, res) => {
            if (!err) {
                done()
            } else {
                done(err);
            }
        });
  });

  //  .......

});


// controller code where the session is set;

// .....

req.session.clientData = clientData;

// ....
```

When I run the code I get the following error: 
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (C:\Nedbank\aa-serverui\application\tests\authorise.js)

But if I comment out the session setting line ( // req.session.clientData = clientData; ) then the test continues to run as expected.

Comment: Without seeing more on your controller, should you be setting the session on the `res` instead of the `req`? Seems more like an issue with your app code then the test code at the moment.

Comment: @AndrewNolan no. The code is correct. The application runs perfectly. The reason the session is set on the req is that the controller will pass the req to another controller then the controller would then get the session data from there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an minimal working example:

`app.js`:

```js
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const app = express();

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "keyboard cat",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true },
  }),
);

function controller(req, res) {
  const clientData = req.query;
  console.log(clientData);
  req.session.clientData = clientData;
  res.sendStatus(302);
}

app.get("/router", controller);

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

module.exports = app;
```

`app.test.js`:

```js
const supertest = require("supertest");
const app = require("./app");
const agent = supertest(app);
const { expect } = require("chai");

describe("Check if endpoint are reachable", () => {
  const clientData = { name: "supertest" };
  before((done) => {
    agent
      .get("/router")
      .query(clientData)
      .expect(302)
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (!err) {
          done();
        } else {
          done(err);
        }
      });
  });

  it("should pass", async () => {
    const res = await agent.get("/api");
    expect(res.status).to.be.eq(200);
  });
});
```

Integration test result with coverage report:

```sh
  Check if endpoint are reachable
{ name: 'supertest' }
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (44ms)

-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File         |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files    |    96.15 |       50 |      100 |    96.15 |                   |
 app.js      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 app.test.js |    92.86 |       50 |      100 |    92.86 |                17 |
-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/56526009

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same issue and eventually determined the cause was jest.useFakeTimers()  I don't know why, but removing that made the test behave as expected.